# How can I get cloud integration working again in Android 5.1?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, system, cloud

When I tap Cloud in system settings, nothing happens. At first I thought it was because my odex file was messed up, but I fixed that and the permissions are set correctly. Cloudhub.apk is also present in /system/app, but I can't find an entry in the dalvik cache. Is there a way I can reinstall this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself, I figured out I needed to use the original Cloudhub.apk that came with my stock firmware. I was trying to use one pulled from a G3, and that's a no-go. If anyone runs into this issue, make sure you use an original APK, odex file and dummy library file pulled from the system apps directory of original Stylo firmware. And permissions must be set correctly. That should solve the problem and allow you full access to cloud services in the photo Gallery and elsewhere.